# Identifying HTML dropdown selection in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have my html code:

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="pan" class="radioButton" value="pan">
  <label for="pan">PAN</label>
  <input type="radio" id="singleColor" class="radioButton" value="singleColor">
  <label for="singleColor"> 
       <span>
           <select name="imageColor">
               <option value="red" selected="selected">Red</option>
               <option value="red">Green</option>
               <option value="red">Blue</option>
           </select>
       </span>
    </label>
</form>
```

What I want to do with this is have the functionality that when the user selects the radio button for Single Color - the choice in the drop down is the choice for the color of the image.  So, initially Red is there at the beginning, so if I just clicked on the radio button then it would grab the red image.  If I selected "Blue" from the dropdown then that value would be passed and it would grab a blue image.  I plan on having an ajax for this, I was just curious as to how I can set up jQuery to read this in.  For example:

```
$("#singleColor").on('click', function() {
   
    if(selected === "red") {
       //Ajax code to call red image in
    }
    if(selected === "blue") {
       //Ajax code to call blue image in
    }
    $("#singleColor").change(function() {
       //identify the current value (i.e. Red, Blue, or Green)
       //Call Ajax for what ever is selected
});
```

Something like the above. I just don't know how to pass in what is selected in the code to be able to identify which @RequestMapping to call based on the users selection.

If I didn't explain this correctly please let me know I'm happy to go more in depth.

Thank you!

Comment: The value (JavaScript: `.value`, jQuery: `.val()`) of the select element will tell you what was is currently selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `value` of each of your `option`s to the color name and then you can use `$("#imageColor").val()` to get the selected option's value. Note that you do not need to wrap your `select` in a `label` and a `span` as that does not do anything.

```js
$("#imageColor").change(function(e){
  console.log($(this).val());
  switch($(this).val()){
    case "red":
      //Ajax code to call red image in
      break;
    case "blue":
      //Ajax code to call blue image in
      break;
    case "green":
      //Ajax code to call green image in
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="pan" class="radioButton" value="pan">
  <label for="pan">PAN</label>
  <input type="radio" id="singleColor" class="radioButton" value="singleColor">
     <select id="imageColor">
         <option value="red" selected="selected">Red</option>
         <option value="green">Green</option>
         <option value="blue">Blue</option>
     </select>
</form>
```